# Trying to Concatenate a Variable with contact details.

Tags: javascript, html, concatenation

Could someone please help me with this problem, I am trying to achieve a drop down select button that shows the releant providers for courses once clicked on, however the majority of courses have multiple providers (6-8)

I have all my providers going through a variable and when I try to Concatenate, it results in blank.

Can someone please help, it would be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<label for="programSelect">  Please choose a Programme<br><br></label>
<select id="nearestStore">
  <option value="noSelection">Please Select</option>
  <option value="StudyP">Study Programmes</option>
  <option value="Train">Traineeships</option>
  <option value="Acc">Accountancy</option>
  <option value="Agri">Agricultural and Land Based</option>
  <option value="Anim">Animal Care</option>
  <option value="Beauty">Beauty Therapy</option>
  <option value="Busin">Business Improvement Tech</option>
  <option value="Busina">Business Administration</option>
  <option value="CallC">Call Centres</option>
  <option value="Creative">Creative arts</option>
  <option value="Construct">Construction</option>
  <option value="Customer">Customer service</option>
  <option value="Cyber">Cyber Security</option>
  <option value="Early">Early years ChildCare & Education</option>
  <option value="Electro">ElectroTechnical</option>
  <option value="Electric">Electricity Industry</option>
</select>



 <div id="phoneNumber"></div>

 <script>
  var nearestStore = document.getElementById("nearestStore"),
      phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber"),

      contactdetails = {
        noSelection: "",
        StudyP: "<br><a href='http://www.howcollege.ac.uk'>Heart of         Worcestershire College</a><br>Emily Leleu<br>01905 743587<br>",

        Train: "<br><a href='http://www.howcollege.ac.uk'>Heart of Worcestershire College</a><br>Emily Leleu<br>01905 743587",


    }

   nearestStore.onchange = function(){
    phoneNumber.innerHTML = contactdetails[this.value];
    contactdetails.StudyP: += '<a     href='http://www.warwickshire.ac.uk/colleges/henley-in-arden.aspx'>Henley in           Arden College</a><br>Personname<br>number<br><br>';

    }



</script>
```

Comment: "contactdetails.StudyP:" what is the ' : ' here?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are forming a string is wrong, it has to do with single quote('') and double quote(""). And also, you have a colon (:). The modified line is

```
contactdetails.StudyP += "<a href='http://www.warwickshire.ac.uk/colleges/henley-in-arden.aspx'>Henley in Arden College</a><br>Personname<br>number<br><br>";
```

replace your line with this.

Comment: Thankyou for fast response and correction, adding/replacing that line in has allowed for the first string of StudyP to appear but the concatenated string does not appear below it.

Comment: Perhpas it is to do with the placement of the string?

Comment: Can you be more specific, where do you want the string to appear, do you  want something like this.
`//phoneNumber.innerHTML = contactdetails[this.value];
 var previousString = contactdetails.StudyP;
 previousString = previousString.concat("<a href='http://www.warwickshire.ac.uk/colleges/henley-in-arden.aspx'>Henley in Arden College</a><br>Personname<br>number<br><br>");
 phoneNumber.innerHTML = previousString;`

Comment: That works great! I am implementing this into a Wordpress site and I am placing the code into the Page itself, however when I save and try running it, none of the details appear when selected.

Comment: Could it be a compatibility issue with HTML and Javascript within Wordpress? I was under the assumption that Wordpress was capable of this.

Comment: In terms of where the string should appear, it would be below the original string with a break.